# arabluatex: Underlining an Arabic text

Tags: luatex, arabic, underline, arabluatex

How to fix the following underlined Arabic text?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tuenc]{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}[Script=Arabic, RawFeature={+anum}]
\usepackage{arabluatex}

\begin{document}

Without underlining:

\begin{txarab}
    كتاب
\end{txarab}

With underlining

\begin{txarab}
\underline{كتاب}
\end{txarab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\underline` knows nothing about arabic text. Use:

```
\begin{txarab}
\underline{\begin{txarab}كتاب\end{txarab}}
\end{txarab}
```

[image]

or define your own `\arabuline` which does the `\begin .. \end` automatically

Answer (score 1):

There might be different solutions, but I find the following one working using `ulem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tuenc]{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}[Script=Arabic, RawFeature={+anum}]
\usepackage{arabluatex,ulem}

\begin{document}

Without underlining:

\begin{txarab}
    كتاب
\end{txarab}

With underlining

\begin{txarab}
\uline{كتاب}
\end{txarab}

\end{document}
```

[image]